# Tiles as a navigation

Tags: menus

I would like to make a menu in such a way that each item in the menu would be a separate tile (look attachment) [image]

It's possible? 
I have already code:

```
<?php 

  $my_menu = array( 
  'menu' => 'menu-oferta',
  'container' => 'padding-offer',
  'items_wrap' => '%3$s'

  );




  wp_nav_menu( $my_menu );



?>
```

but I need a class that will be between separating LI, preferably a DIV. I would like to achieve this effect

```
  <div class="class">

 <li class=""> 

  <a href=""> LINK 1 </a>

 </li>

</div>
```

Comment: This is certainly possible, it's just a matter of styling, which is a CSS thing. I don't see the need for a div though? Just make the `li` elements and `a` elements `display:block` then either float them or use grid layout to make them square and appear in a grid

Comment: it will not help me. I need a DIV because I need to set PADDING for these tiles. Because if I set Padding for LI it's just inside. And I don't want them to touch each other. Other ideas?

Comment: Grid would let you specify margin between them. Even floating would let you put margin on them to keep them from touching.

Comment: `.li { margin: 5px; float:left; } a { display: block; width:100px; height:100px; }` would do the trick? It's a crude version of a proper solution, but it works. The `div` is not necessary, and there are multiple ways to do it without one